# use "net Use" to set default printer in batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch, printer

I have to create a batch file to set the users default personal printer to lpt1 in a Windows 7 environment.

Searching the web I found this and this:

```
net Use lpt1 \\\computername\printer
```

I know can use `%computername%` to get the computer name and I can use this to get the default printer name: `cscript %Windir%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-us\prnmngr.vbs -g`

But I do not know how to combine the 2 into one "net use" statement in my batch file.

The end result I would like is `net Use lpt1 \\itwin7003\hp laserjet 2035`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I have to create a batch file to set the users default personal printer to lpt1

Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in (`wmic printer where default^="true" get sharename ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set _printer=%%i
  rem remove trailing cr
  set _printer=!_printer:~0,-1!
  net use lpt1 "\\%computername%\!_printer!"
  )
)
endlocal
```

Command line:

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %i in (`wmic printer where default^="true" get sharename ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do @net use lpt1 \\%computername%\%i
```

Note:

- `net use` requires the printer `ShareName`.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [net](http://ss64.com/nt/net.html)  - The NET Command is used to manage network resources.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: HI David, thanks for the prompt reply.  When i run the command line I only get the NET USE information as if I were to just type NET USE /?  Also when i use the batch file code i get "System error 66 has occurred" and the network resource type is not correct'

Comment: @goofus828 This may need tweaking if there are spaces in the printer name. Please let me know.

Comment: Yes some of the workstations' printer may contain spaces.  This batch file is going to run from 60-200 users so each printer is obviously different.

Comment: @goofus828 Can you please try the updated batch file?

Comment: umm. is the original post updated?  No sure where it is.  sorry

Comment: @goofus828 It is now. Forgot to press save - was looking up the error 66

Comment: Got it, tried it and it said "new connections will be remembered" but when I do NET USE i don't see it.  Should I?

Comment: @goofus828 Note: net use requires the printer ShareName. That is not the same as the printer name. I've updated the answer again.

Comment: @goofus828 Note I can't test it here as I don't have a network ...

Comment: OK.  I'll have to test it on a workstation..  I appreciate all your help and will post the results.